# White field on the site on the right on Tilda (with a very short third-party code)

Tags: html, css, web

i'm completely don't know css and html code, so pls I need little help!! Thanks in advance!

So I have a site on Tilda with a couple short third-party codes.
And if i scroll site Not down but sideways, so i see white field.
Actually it appears on monitor 16:10 (8:5) aspect ratio.

When I Off this code, the problem goes away, but I need this cos I need menu-header Semi-transparent and so that the background picture would lie under it.

Here is *(and one more similar, but with another #rec and z-index)*:

```
<style>
#rec494906714 {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 9998;
}
</style>
```

And here https://kvant-mebel.com.ua site 2 screenshots:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you add your body tag in css this: overflow-x: hidden;

Comment: @berkesasa ookay, but can you explain more details please? And try add this here https://imgur.com/a/SS2gHBG. But seems i'm wrong

Comment: @berkesasa or you mean inside of this short code?

Answer (score 0):

When I look again, adding it to the class you gave above seems to solve the problem. But I'm not sure this is the right solution.

```
<style>
#rec494906714 {
    overflow-x: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 9998;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Hmm, it works cool, buuuut there a problem, I have SVG pictures on it (flags) - [link](https://imgur.com/TUy0I2d), so I need them to overflow - [link](https://imgur.com/LFgd44q)

Comment: Maybe you can change flag's z-index or adding overflow-y-hidden. Can you try?

Comment: Hm, also still cuting flags. I change overflow-x: hidden; to overflow-y: hidden; ! And also try add both

Comment: Did you try flag's z-index. Give its = z-index:999

Comment: yes, also the same, no new effect. Still cutting, I try diff combination from your advices. So overflow-y: hidden write with overflow-x: hidden, or without ? (but seems I already try with and without)